# Sum of $\sum_{1\leq k\leq k'\leq n}\frac{k^{\alpha}}{k'^{\alpha}}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to calculute or estimate of order $O(n^{2-\varepsilon})$, where $\varepsilon>0$, of the following sum for $0<\alpha<1$
$$\sum_{1\leq k\leq k'\leq n}\frac{k^{\alpha}}{k'^{\alpha}}.$$

Comment: Bound it by an integral.

Answer (score 1):

Consider all pairs $(k,k')$ with $\frac{n}{4}\leq k\leq\frac{n}{2}\leq k'\leq\frac{3n}{4}$. There are $\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$ such pairs and for them $\frac{k}{k'}\geq\frac{1}{3}$. So the sum is bounded from below by 
$\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\alpha$,
and thus as $n\to\infty$ is not $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: What about $O(\frac{n^2}{\log(n)})$.

Comment: the factor $3^{-\alpha}$ is $O(1)$